# How to call mouse functions on embed data?

Tags: javascript, svg, embedded-resource, mouse-cursor

I have some embed svg files on my website. I would like to use onmouseclick, onmouseout, and onmousemove functions on them, but they don't works. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: did you tried anything ? paste some code here

Comment: I gave wmode="transparent" to the embed, and a mouseclick function to the parent div, but it doesn't works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only possible if the embedded SVG script is served from the same domain. After the embedded content has finished loading, you want to get hold of the actual svg document with `getSVGDocument`. From there you add the events. Check out this demo:

rect.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     version="1.1"
     width="300"
     height="200">
  <rect x="50" y="25" width="200" height="150" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

eventsDemo.js

```
var log, emb, svgDoc, rect;

log = function ( e ) {
  console.log( e.type );
};

emb = document.querySelector( 'embed' );

emb.addEventListener( 'load', function () {
  svgDoc = emb.getSVGDocument();
  rect   = svgDoc.querySelector( 'rect' );

  rect.addEventListener( 'click',     log );
  rect.addEventListener( 'mousemove', log );
  rect.addEventListener( 'mouseout',  log );
} );
```

demo.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <embed type='image/svg+xml' src='rect.svg'>
  <script src='eventsDemo.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```